How to explain why $ \lim _{m+1 \rightarrow \infty} x^m=\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} x^m=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} x^n$ here?
I am reading Tao's Analysis I for my own pleasure, and in this example he gave in his section Why do Analysis I was confused what the (non-rigorous) reasoning employed there could be, where $n = m+1$:

Let $x$ be a real number, and let $L$ be the limit
$$
L=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} x^n .
$$

Changing variables $n=m+1$, we have
$$
L=\lim _{m+1 \rightarrow \infty} x^{m+1}=\lim _{m+1 \rightarrow \infty} x \times x^m=x \lim _{m+1 \rightarrow \infty} x^m .
(1)$$
But if $m+1 \rightarrow \infty$, then $m \rightarrow \infty$, thus
$$
\lim _{m+1 \rightarrow \infty} x^m=\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} x^m=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} x^n=L,
$$
In $(1)$, I am unsure of the reasoning for both going past the first equals sign and the second equals sign. Without delving into how limits are rigorously defined (as I haven't gotten there yet), what could be reasoning behind this statement here?
For the first equals sign, is it that we want to see what $x^m$ approaches when $m+1$ is "approaching" $\infty$- and when $m+1$ "approaches" $\infty$, the phenomenon of $m$ approaching $\infty$ is also underway, so whatever $x^m$ approaches when $m$ approaches $
\infty$ is something it would approach when $m + 1$ "approaches" $\infty$?
For the second equals sign, is it that the converse of the statement Tao gives is true, namely that if $m$ approaches $\infty$, $m+1$ approaches $\infty$? In particular, I am confused about why we can substitute the exponent $m$ for $n$ here.
EDIT: What exactly does the relation, $n=m+1$, mean (which was used in the change of variables)- as both $n$ and $m$ fluctuate their values, in what context are we saying that $n = m+1$?Are we saying that whenever we "consider" $n=a$ where $a$ is some number, we "consider" $m=a+1$?

The first equals sign, you are right. As $m+1\to\infty$, we also have $m\to\infty$ (whatever we define the limit to be rigorously, you hope this makes sense since it is intuitive).
For the second equals sign, $m$ or $n$ is a dummy variable. It does not matter the variable you use. You might as well have
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}x^m=\lim_{\to\infty}x^{}$$
and it does not matter. The final limit does not depend on $m$, is the key point.
Hope this helps. :)

thanks; for the second equals sign, we did say $n = m + 1$ though. I think I understand the reasoning now; but how could $m$ or $n$ be a dummy variables with respect to each other when they are defined to be related to each other in this way? what exactly do you mean by "dummy variable"? Thanks :)

A dummy variable is a variable that only exists within a limit (or other expression). For example, the expression we have here is a function only in $x$ (i.e. its value depends on the value of $x$) because $m$ belongs to the limit and you can only refer to it in the context of that limit. It's fine to transform between dummy variables as long as you completely substitute all of its appearances (so you replace $n$ with $m+1$ everywhere it occurs in the limit).

@PrincessMia: all you are looking for is the limit of the sequence $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, $\dots$. Doesn't matter how you choose to represent the general term by -- $x^n$ and then take limit as $n\to\infty$ or $n^2\to\infty$ etc.
